# Remove First 16 Bytes?

Tags: c#, arrays

How would I go about removing a number of bytes from a byte array?

Comment: Another flawed SO question, we've been getting a lot of them lately.  Distinguished by a single sentence question that doesn't do much to explain the title.  By far the best approach is to not do it.  Many methods that take an array have an overload that take an offset and length.  There's even a dedicated class for it: ArraySegment<T>.  Whether that would help you is quite unclear from your question.  Probably not.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

EDIT: As nobugz's comment (and Reed Copsey's answer) mentions, if you don't actually need the result as a byte array, you should look into using [`ArraySegment<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx):

```
ArraySegment<byte> segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(full, 16, full.Length - 16);
```

Otherwise, copying will be necessary - arrays always have a fixed size, so you can't "remove" the first 16 bytes from the existing array. Instead, you'll have to create a new, smaller array and copy the relevant data into it.

Zach's suggestion is along the right lines for the non-LINQ approach, but it can be made simpler (this assumes you already know the original array is at least 16 bytes long):

```
byte[] newArray = new byte[oldArray.Length - 16];
Buffer.BlockCopy(oldArray, 16, newArray, 0, newArray.Length);
```

or

```
byte[] newArray = new byte[oldArray.Length - 16];
Array.Copy(oldArray, 16, newArray, 0, newArray.Length);
```

I *suspect* `Buffer.BlockCopy` will be slightly faster, but I don't know for sure.

Note that both of these could be significantly more efficient than the LINQ approach if the arrays involved are big: the LINQ approach requires each byte to be individually returned from an iterator, and potentially intermediate copies to be made (in the same way as adding items to a `List<T>` needs to grow the backing array periodically). Obviously don't micro-optimise, but it's worth *checking* if this bit of code is a performance bottleneck.

EDIT: I ran a very "quick and dirty" benchmark of the three approaches. I don't trust the benchmark to distinguish between `Buffer.BlockCopy` and `Array.Copy` - they were pretty close - but the LINQ approach was over 100 times slower.

On my laptop, using byte arrays of 10,000 elements, it took nearly 10 seconds to perform 40,000 copies using LINQ; the above approaches took about 80ms to do the same amount of work. I upped the iteration count to 4,000,000 and it still only took about 7 seconds. Obviously the normal caveats around micro-benchmarks apply, but this is a pretty significat difference.

Definitely use the above approach if this is in a code path which is important to performance :)

Comment: What's the difference between Buffer.BlockCopy and Array.Copy when used with byte arrays?

Comment: @dtb: I don't expect there to be any functional difference in this case. `Buffer.BlockCopy` is a bit more restrictive - I suspect it's implemented in a lower-level manner, but I don't know the details.

Comment: @dtb: It appears from the msdn documentation that `Array.Copy` copies the array one element at a time (the docs say: `This method is an O(n) operation, where n is length`), but `Buffer.BlockCopy` copies a block of bytes as a whole (I assume creating another array temporarily to store the copied bytes).

Comment: @Zach: Why would either of them need a temporary array, unless they're copying from one section of an array to an overlapping section of the same array?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It sounds like from the documentation on `Buffer.BlockCopy`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx, that it is intended for use where you may copy overlapping sections.  

From the docs: "As its name suggests, the BlockCopy method copies a block of bytes as a whole, rather than copying one byte at a time. Therefore, if src and dst reference the same array, and the range from srcOffset + count -1 overlaps the range from dstOffset + count - 1, the values of the overlapping bytes are not overwritten before they are copied to the destination."

Comment: @Zach: It's intended to *cope* with overlapping sections, but I doubt that it copies twice if it doesn't need to.

Answer (score 17):

You could do this:

```
using System.Linq

// ...

var newArray = oldArray.Skip(numBytes).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

I will also mention - depending on how you plan to use the results, often, an alternative approach is to use [`ArraySegment<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) to just access the remaining portion of the array.  This prevents the need to copy the array, which can be more efficient in some usage scenarios:

```
ArraySegment<byte> segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(originalArray, 16, originalArray.Length-16);

// Use segment how you'd use your array...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use Linq, you could do it this way:

```
byte[] myArray = // however you acquire the array

byte[] newArray = new byte[myArray.Length - 16];

for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
{
    newArray[i] = myArray[i + 16];
}

// newArray is now myArray minus the first 16 bytes
```

You'll also need to handle the case where the array is less than 16 bytes long.